# Python - Take weighted average inside Pandas groupby while ignoring NaN

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I need to group a Pandas dataframe by date, and then take a weighted average of given values.  Here's how it's currently done using the margin value as an example (and it works perfectly until there are NaN values):

```
df = orders.copy()
# Create new columns as required
df['margin_WA'] = df['net_margin'].astype(float)    # original data as str or Decimal

def group_wa():
        return lambda num: np.average(num, weights=df.loc[num.index, 'order_amount'])

agg_func = {
        'margin_WA': group_wa(),    # agg_func includes WAs for other elements
    }

result = df.groupby('order_date').agg(agg_func)

result['margin_WA'] = result['margin_WA'].astype(str)
```

In the case where `'net_margin'` fields contain `NaN` values, the WA is set to NaN.  I can't seem to be able to `dropna()` or filtering by `pd.notnull` when creating new columns, and I don't know where to create a masked array to avoid passing `NaN` to the `group_wa` function ([like suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35758345/2524282)).  How do I ignore `NaN` in this case?

Answer (score 4):

I think a simple solution is to drop the missing values before you groupby/aggregate like:

```
 result = df.dropna(subset='margin_WA').groupby('order_date').agg(agg_func)
```

In this case, no indices containing missings are passed to your `group_wa` function.

#### Edit

Another approach is to move the `dropna` into your aggregating function like:

```
def group_wa(series):
    dropped = series.dropna()
    return np.average(dropped, weights=df.loc[dropped.index, 'order_amount'])

agg_func = {'margin_WA': group_wa}
result = df.groupby('order_date').agg(agg_func)
```

Comment: Fair.  I was hoping not to because I want to include an order with a NaN net margin for calculating gross margin (non-NaN) for example, so it would require creating different dataframes for different values.  Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @user2524282 Updated the answer.

Comment: Or alternatively, in one line,
`group_wa = lambda x: np.average(x.dropna(), weights=df.loc[x.dropna().index, 'order_amount'])`

Thank you though; I've been looking for a solution to this problem for a long time, and this is the best solution I've seen!